# Why does perturbation theory work for helium atoms?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, perturbation-theory, approximations, orbitals

I saw the following argument for calculating the energy levels of a helium atom.

First, ignore the Coulomb interaction term between two electrons. For this simplified model, we have the same solutions as in the hydrogen atom: so let's say that electron 1 is in $\psi_1=\psi_{n,l,m}$ and electron 2 is in $\psi_2 = \psi_{n', l', m'}$.

Now since these electrons are indistinguishable, we must antisymmetrize or symmetrize the spatial wavefunction.  (These correspond to orthohelium/parahelium respectively.)

$$ \psi = \frac 1 {\sqrt 2}(\psi_1(r_1)\psi_2(r_2)\pm \psi_2(r_1)\psi_1(r_2))$$

Then according to the first-order perturbation theory, we calculate

$$\left\langle \psi \left| \frac{ e^2 }{4 \pi \epsilon_0 |r_1 - r_2| } \right| \psi \right\rangle.$$

However, since the energy levels are degenerate, we must find some 'good quantum numbers' for the above formula to be correct.
I cannot see what are these 'good quantum numbers' for the helium atom. This is because the perturbation $H' = \frac{ e^2 }{4 \pi \epsilon_0 |r_1 - r_2| }$ does not commute with the usual operators for $n,l, m$.

Could somebody help me, please?

Comment: Perturbation theory does not require the perturbation to commute with the unperturbed hamiltonian. Why do you think so?

Comment: As far as I know: In the degenerate case, not all eigenfunctions of the Hamiltonian can be used as a starting point. That is, even if $H^{(0)} \psi^{(0)} = E^{(0)} \psi^{(0)}$, there might not exist a curve $\psi(\lambda) = \psi ^{(0)} + \lambda \psi^{(1)} + \lambda ^2 \psi^{(2)} + \cdots$ which is a eigenfunction of $ H^{(0)}  + \lambda H'$ for each $\lambda \in [0,1]$.

Comment: However, there is a sufficient condition that guarantees that such a series expansion is valid. One such condition: the initial eigenbasis we have chosen are described by 'good' quantum numbers (this is the terminology from Griffiths' QM book, may not be standard...)

Comment: That is, there exists a commuting family of Hermitian operators $A_i$ which also satisfies $[A_i,H^{(0)}]=0$ and $[A_i,H']=0$ such that the initial eigenbasis chosen consists of simultaneous eigenvectors of all these $A_i$'s, and moreover, for any two elements in the eigenbasis corresponding to the same eigenenergy, there exists an $i$ such that the corresponding eigenvalues w.r.t. $A_i$ are distinct.

Comment: The terminology '[good quantum number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Good_quantum_number)' is standard. You should also look up the term '[complete set of commuting observables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_set_of_commuting_observables)' (CSCO), which is the correct formal description for your $A_i$.

Comment: The condition you've stated is excessively restrictive, by far. If there is a CSCO which commutes with both the unperturbed hamiltonian $H^{(0)}$ and the perturbation $H'$ (i.e. $[A_i,H']=0$) then there is no need for perturbation theory $-$ $H'$ is already diagonal in the CSCO eigenbasis. (To prove this, take any two basis states $|\phi⟩$, $|\psi⟩$, and $A_i$ with distinct eigenvalues for both, from which $⟨\phi|[H',A_i]|\psi⟩=0$ implies  $⟨\phi|H'|\psi⟩=0$, i.e. all off-diagonal elements of $H'$ are zero.) Where did you find the claim that this condition is necessary? It is not in Griffiths.

Comment: ... and neither is the claim that the curve $\psi(\lambda)$ might not exist. What specific source are you taking that from? (It would also help to be very specific regarding whether this is for degenerate or non-degenerate perturbation theory.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118342/discussion-between-moca-aoba-and-emilio-pisanty).